# JavaFX : Binding button disable property to ComboBox and DatePicker

Tags: binding, combobox, javafx, datepicker, javafx-8

My fxml contains a TextField, a ComboBox, a DatePicker and a Button that should only be enabled when the objects above are not empty.

```
@FXML private TextField numText;
@FXML private ComboBox societeComboBox;
@FXML private DatePicker dateCreationPicker; 

@FXML private Button ajoutBtn;
```

i figured out how to bind the disable property of the button to the TextField but i can't figure out how to do the same for the ComboBox and the DatePicker.

```
 ajoutBtn.disableProperty().bind(
        Bindings.isEmpty(numText.textProperty())  );
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both the ComboBox and the DatePicker have `valueProperty` that can be used for checking their emptiness. You can `OR` them to `disableProperty` of the button

```
ajoutBtn.disableProperty().bind(
        numText.textProperty().isEmpty()
        .or( societeComboBox.valueProperty().isNull() )
        .or( dateCreationPicker.valueProperty().isNull() ) );
```